# Parse error for embedded linux

Tags: parse-error

Trying to build embedded linux for raspberry pi 3...

Using command: bitbake rpi-basic-image

```
echo 'MACHINE = "raspberrypi3"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.%"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"' >> conf/local.conf
echo 'VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"' >> conf/local.conf
echo ‘ENABLE_UART = “1”’ >> conf/local.conf
```

receiving the error 
    ERROR: ParseError at /../conf/local.conf:1: unparsed line: ' echo MACHINE = 
    "raspberrypi3" >> rpi-build/conf/local.conf'